# CSS table columns and forming x% of the table

Tags: css

I am preparing Asp.net website. On my style sheet, i want my table to have those properties:

```
table {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}
```

Table's first column should **form 20% of the whole table.** 
And my second column should form 80% of the table. And i am not sure how to design differently 2 columns in css. But i think it should be like this:

```
table td.first {
}
table td.second {
}
```

My regards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually one gives an id to the table columns this way:

```
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td id="first-column">... content ...</td>
    <td id="second-column">... content ...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can adress the columns in css this way:

```
table#my-table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
table#my-table td#first-column {
  width: 20%;
}
table#my-table td#second-column {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are simply trying to target a specific column in your table. Just give your `<td>`'s an id like:

`<td id="columnOne">`... etc

You target them in the CSS using this syntax...

either:

```
table td#columnOne { *styles* }
```

or simply:

```
#columnOne { *styles* }
```

This method is safer and more compatible than using pseudo classes as I think you are trying to do, which would be:

```
table td:first-child { *styles* }
```

and:

```
table td:nth-child(2) { *styles* }
```

Comment: Yes i was trying to target specific column in my table. This seems like working fine. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I wish i could, it requires 15 reputation on the website :) Thanks again